# How to change a value of a field in model only a current user?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a field 'progress' in Level

```
class Level(models.Model):
    level = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    helper = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    progress = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I need to add 1 to 'progress'. All I need is to store a different value for every user.
I really cannot figure it out how to dot it.
Now I have a class LevelProgress in views.py that adds 1 to the field of progress, but it adds 1 globally.

```
class LevelProgress(APIView):

    def get(self, request, id):
        queryset_ = Level.objects.get(pk=id)
        queryset_.progress += 1
        queryset_.save()
        serializer = LevelFullSerializer(queryset_)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

How can I add 1 for a current user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the modeling is incorrect. You can not store the progress on that `Level` object, you need to add an extra model, for example `UserLevel` with `ForeignKey`s to the `User` and the `Level`, and increment that one:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Level(models.Model):
    level = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    helper = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class UserLevel(models.Model):
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    progress = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

So now we construct for a `User` a specific `UserLevel` object, and we can update that progress. We can even do this with a single `update_or_create(..)` function:

```
class LevelProgress(APIView):

    def get(self, request, id):
        ul, created = UserLevel.objects.get_or_create(
           level_id=id,
           user_id=request.user.pk
           defaults={'progress': 1}
        )
        if not created:
            ul.progress += 1
            ul.save()
        serializer = LevelFullSerializer(ul.level)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

You also might want to change the `LevelFullSerializer` to serialize the progress of that user.

That being said, a GET request with "side-effects" is actually not allowed according to the HTTP guidelines. Normally one changes the entities in a database with POST, PUT, PATCH, etc. requests.

Comment: when I'm trying to create, I'm getting ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "UserLevel.user" must be a "User" instance. 
what do I do wrong?

Comment: @MikeRu: ah, it should be `user_id=...`, not `user=..`, sorry, made a typo.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `OneToOneField` field to `Level` model like this:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Level(models.Model):
    level = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    helper = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    progress = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now in your view you can get level for current user:

```
class LevelProgress(APIView):

    def get(self, request, id):
        queryset_ = Level.objects.get(user=request.user)
        queryset_.progress += 1
        queryset_.save()
        serializer = LevelFullSerializer(queryset_)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```